# How to Use TRUNC Function into VBA Available in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to use TRUNC function, which is available in Excel, into VBA. I noticed that it is not available in Application.WorksheetFunction. how can I get it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/int-fix-functions

Comment: @BigBen according to your source this function is not available in my **Excel API** version. I'll geti round it somehow. thanks.

Comment: I'm proposing that you use `Fix`.

Comment: Or use `WorksheetFunction.Floor()`

Comment: Please show the code that you are trying to use `TRUNC()` in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a VBA equivalent, something like:

```
Function vbaTRUNC(num As Double, Optional digits As Long = 0) As Double
    vbaTRUNC = Fix(num * 10 ^ digits) / 10 ^ digits
End Function
```

Comment: that's what I finally did. I just wanted something native but there's no way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split function and split on `.`

```
NewStr = split(string, ".")(0)
```

Comment: This is a string though - you'd need to `CLng`. And it is still overkill. `Fix` does this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `TRUNC` instead of `Fix` because you need to specify the number of decimal places remaining after truncation, you can use `Application.Evaluate` to do something this:

```
Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("=TRUNC(3.14159265359, 4)")
'will return 3.1415
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your pick. All the functions below return the value of `2` for `2.71828182845905`

Public Sub TestTT()

```
Dim x As Double
x = Exp(1)

Debug.Print x, WorksheetFunction.Floor(x, 1)
Debug.Print x, Fix(x)
Debug.Print x, CLng(x)
Debug.Print x, WorksheetFunction.Round(x - 0.5, 0)
```

End Sub